# Projective module over a commutative ring $R$ becomes free over some ring containing $R$ .

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

I am reposting this as earlier question was probably not clear to some.

So I was reading a book in which we have a commutative ring $A$, a commutative algebra over it called $B$ and a set of projective modules over $B$, say $X_i$. The book has following statement

"the modules $X_i$ are projective, hence become free (of rank 1) over a suitable ring $C$ containing $B$."

This statement was only used and not proved. I have never seen something similar so I don't know how and why is it true. I simply tried googling it but I couldn't find anything. If someone here has seen a similar result and they can either explain it or lead me to a reference text then I will be grateful.

Edit : for the (rank 1) part, it is possible that this is true only in given situation and not in general. For bit more context the modules $X_i$ are $e_iB^d$ where $d$ is some positive integer and $\{e_i\}$ form a finite family of orthogonal idempotents of $B$ whose sum is identity of $B$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for taking the time to make these improvements. If you know the book though you should really say what it is.  People might want to look at the context on their own.

Comment: Well, I am the one in need so I had to do it :) sorry that I was bit rude earlier

Comment: It's OK.  That reaction is not uncommon, but your recovery is uncommonly good!

Comment: Clearly it suffices to consider just one projective module. But what does "becomes free over $C$" mean? Is it meant that $X \otimes_B C$ is free over $C$? But when it is supposed to be of rank $1$, this cannot possibly work. When on the other hand $X$ is supposed to become a module over $C$ - that is also very unlikely. So as rschwieb wrote: please provide the exact reference. Extra context is required. I am very confident that with that context we will answer your question.

Comment: Maybe relevant: If $X$ is a finitely generated projective $B$-module, then $X$ is locally free (well-known technical result). That is, there are finitely many elements $f_1,\dotsc,f_n \in B$ generating the unit ideal in such a way that each $X[f_i^{-1}]$ is a free $B[f_i^{-1}]$-module of finite rank $n_i$. Now take $C := \prod_{i=1}^{n} B[f_i^{-1}]$. Then $B \to C$ is injective and $X \otimes_B C$ is the next-best-thing to a free $C$-module: it would be free if the $n_i$ were constant.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg the rank 1 part was pointed out by someone else too and for that I have made an edit which provides little more context. Other than that there is not much to add except adding the entire context which will be difficult. The best I can do after this point is cite the reference book and page.

Comment: I will look at your other comment later. It does look like it's in right direction. Meanwhile if you can add more with the additional context then you are welcome.

Comment: Is that claim even true? Consider a field $A=k$, $B=k\times k$ and let $M=k\times 0$, which is a projective $B$-module (but not free). Now if $k$ is finite, of size $n$, then $|B|=n^2$ but $|M|=n$. So how can $M$ be a free module over some ring containing $B$? That isn't possible, the cardinalities don't match. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you can give us the name of the book? And where exactly this statement is? Because I'm quite confident that it is false as it is.

Comment: @freakish book is "p-adic families of galois representations and higher rank selmer groups" by Bellaiche and Chenevier. Page no 22. These are very last two lines. Sure there is whole lot of context there but the way they have written this indicated as if this was a general rule.